# Visual Studio Code not recognising PHP on Linux

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

So I've set the "php.validate.executablePath" to "/usr/bin/php" in the user settings but keep getting this message

> Cannot validate since /usr/bin/php is not a valid php executable. Use
>   the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP
>   executable.

additional info:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 25 12:26 /usr/bin/php ->
>   /etc/alternatives/php
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 25 12:26 /etc/alternatives/php ->
>   /usr/bin/php7.2
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4895768 Jul  4 18:55 /usr/bin/php7.2

I've installed PHP via apt-get and I'm out of ideas. Anyone with a tipp or the same problem here?

Edit: I've also tried setting php.validate.executablePath to /etc/alternatives/php and /usr/bin/php7.2 which spawned the same message (just with the different paths). Logging off and on again did nothing also.

Comment: Have you tried a couple of obvious things, just to be sure? Inspect `/usr/bin/php7.2` (e.g. `file /usr/bin/php7.2`) and set `php.validate.executablePath` to `/usr/bin/php7.2`?

Comment: Yes I did that. Editing the questions accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one had an explanation, I uninstalled Visual Studio Code and purged php via apt-get and reinstalled both, first PHP, then Visual Studio Code. This time I took the package from the Microsoft page and not the Version form mintinstall. Now it seems to work.

Comment: Same issue, same "solution". The mint package of VSCode seems wrong.

Comment: How to deal with this problem if I don't want to install PHP on my host machine? I use php docker image.

Comment: I suspect the issue I had was that I installed VS Code BEFORE PHP.  

Better to get rid of the flatpak version anyway; the flatpak version of VS Code prompted me to download the latest version of Code from the MS website, which I did without thinking, and then ended up with two copies of Code installed on my system.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was realising the the previous line needed a comma, even though it caught a different error. However, your post is older, and it may have been a newer bug for me:

```
{
"<random junk>":"path/to/junk",
"<more junk>":"path/to/other-junk"
"php.validate.executablePath":"usr/bin/php"
}
```

note that the second last line is missing a comma at the end. For me, I saw this immidately, but VSCode ran a different error saying it couldn't validate (which makes sense because it can't identify the error properly as it can't lint php).